# p5 Using the createAudio callbacks

Tags: p5.js

**TL;DR:** How can I access the audio instances created in the callback of createAdio?

I have the following code in my p5 sketch

```
  // in preload
  sound_a = createAudio('sound_a.mp3'); 

  // in setup
  sound_a.loop();
  sound_a.volume(0.2);
  sound_a.play();
```

This does what I want it to do. However, in my current circumstances, I have multiple audio files for which I wanted to call the same functions. I would want to use a callback to apply the `loop`, `volume` and `play`. My intended behavior is something like this:

```
  // in preload - this would just be a loop 
  sound_a = createAudio('sound_a.mp3', audio_callback); 
  sound_b = createAudio('sound_b.mp3', audio_callback); 
  .....
  sound_z = createAudio('sound_z.mp3', audio_callback); 

  function audio_callback(audio) {
        audio.loop();
        audio.volume(0.2);
        audio.play();
  }
```

However, the callback is not passed any arguments (i.e., `console.log(audio)` returns undefined and `audio.loop()` throws the expected errors.). How can I access the audio created in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're doing `sound_a`, `sound_b`, ... `sound_z`, you [probably want an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript). You can then use loops to avoid repetition and solve the problem you're having by binding an index `i` to each sound:

```js
const urls = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/BILIIE_EILISH.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Bluetooth.ogg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Bismarck71_English_Voice_Sample_%28North_Wind_%26_Sun%29.ogg",
];
let sounds;

function preload() {
  sounds = urls.map((url, i) =>
    createAudio(url, () => {
      sounds[i].volume(0.2);

      // prohibited due to autoplay policy
      // sounds[i].loop();
      // sounds[i].play();
    })
  );
}

function setup() {}

function mousePressed() {
  sounds.forEach(e => {
    e.loop();
    e.play();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<h1>Click anywhere to play</h1>
<h4>File attribution:</h4>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BILIIE_EILISH.ogg">Laidaiturrate</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bluetooth.ogg">Sorondo27</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bismarck71_English_Voice_Sample_(North_Wind_%26_Sun).ogg">Bismarck71</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
```

You could also put the audio object in a data structure alongside each sound rather than in a separate array:

```js
const sounds = [
  {url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/BILIIE_EILISH.ogg"},
  {url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Bluetooth.ogg"},
  {url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Bismarck71_English_Voice_Sample_%28North_Wind_%26_Sun%29.ogg"},
];

function preload() {
  sounds.forEach(e => {
    e.audio = createAudio(e.url, () => {
      e.audio.volume(0.2);

      // prohibited due to autoplay policy
      // e.audio.loop();
      // e.audio.play();
    })
  });
}

function setup() {}

function mousePressed() {
  sounds.forEach(e => {
    e.audio.loop();
    e.audio.play();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<h1>Click anywhere to play</h1>
<h4>File attribution:</h4>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BILIIE_EILISH.ogg">Laidaiturrate</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bluetooth.ogg">Sorondo27</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bismarck71_English_Voice_Sample_(North_Wind_%26_Sun).ogg">Bismarck71</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a>, via Wikimedia Commons
</p>
```

You might wish to [open an issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues) or a PR for implementing the audio as a parameter to the callback.